# Is it approperiate to mix a JSON object with HTML?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, json

With ASP.NET MVC you have the possibility to return a JSONResult.

```
return JSON(new { View = RenderViewAsString("MyView", model), wasSuccessful = true})
```

As you can see my JSON object will have HTML and some data. The idea behind this is to use strongly typed HtmlHelpers in the MVC view and making only one request to the server instead of multiple ones.

Is it approperiate to mix a JSON object with HTML?

Comment: As a long as the HTML is properly contained in the JSON, and consists of valid UTF8 characters, it's not a problem at all ?

Comment: It depends on size-- if this is a small amount of JSON wrapping HTML, then you get the perf qualities of using HTML as a data format. One article I read showed HTML to be the slowest of all possible ways of moving data across the wire (slower than xml, slower than just JSON).  If it is mostly JSON with a little bit of HTML, it probably doesn't make any difference other than preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly effective and will get the job done quickly.

However, if you find yourself getting back ready-made HTML renders from the server together with other data a lot, or if you end up digging into the HTML received to perform "adjustments" before inserting it into the page then you should start looking into client-side templating instead. This way the server can return just the data as JSON and the client will take up the task of rendering the data into HTML independently.